# mpi all to all v in c++

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to generate 4 ints and send them all to P0 using alltoall
I have this: (stack overflow doesn't like linux line endings)

```
int * sendbuf=new int [4];
for(int x=0;x<4;x++){sendbuf[x]=12/4*x;}

 int* sendcounts =new int [4];
 sendcounts[0]=4;
 sendcounts[1]=0;
 sendcounts[2]=0;
 sendcounts[3]=0;

 int* displs=new int [4];
 sendcounts[0]=0*sizeof(int);
 sendcounts[1]=4*sizeof(int);
 sendcounts[2]=4*sizeof(int);
 sendcounts[3]=4*sizeof(int);
 int * recvbuf=new int [16];

for(int x=0;x<16;x++){recvbuf[x]=0;}
 int* recvcounts=new int [4];
 recvcounts[0]=4;
 recvcounts[1]=4;
 recvcounts[2]=4;
 recvcounts[3]=4;

int* rdispls=new int [4];
 rdispls[0]=0;
 rdispls[1]=4;
 rdispls[2]=8;
 rdispls[3]=12;

MPI_Alltoallv(sendbuf,sendcounts,displs,MPI_INT,recvbuf,recvcounts, rdispls,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(id==0)
{
     for(int x=0;x<16;x++){cout<<recvbuf;}
}
```

I get a message truncated error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please edit your question, include a [MCVE] and explain how you run your app. If you need to "send them all to P0", then `MPI_Gather[v]()` is likely a better fit. You might also want to check the semantic difference between `MPI_Alltoallv()` and `MPI_Alltoallw()` with respect to displacements, and initialize `sdispls` (accordingly).

Comment: i cant find any documentation of what they mean by "displacement"

Comment: https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Alltoallv.3.php https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Alltoallw.3.php

Comment: You should not use **sizeof(int)** the size is determined by your **MPI_INT**.